# Mnemonic for vector cross versus dot?

Tags: vectors, mnemonic

I'm always stuck to remember the difference between vector multiplication with dot product versus cross product?

Is there any mnemonic so that I can easily remember which is which?

Comment: This question is not really about physics. Apart from lacking research effort, it may be better suited for a mathematics community.

Comment: Hey gang, I disagree. The questioner is just asking for a **mnemonic** on how to remember this interesting high-school level bit of physics.  I disagree that mathematicians should get this one, damn those guys!  Vectors belong to the physical world and also GPUs.

Comment: Eh, I wouldn't migrate this to math because of the [*don't migrate crap* policy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91446/230312).

Comment: Yes, there are mnemonics for remembering properties of dot and cross vector products: https://wordsandbuttons.online/interactive_mnemonics_for_dot_and_cross_vector_products.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't be easier! The cross is of course a

## cross

i.e., as in say the Christian symbol, the ordinary English word `cross`.

It's called a "cross" because it's two lines crossing.

It's difficult to see how an easier word could be chosen. Since it is a cross of two lines it is called a cross. Again, it's hard to see how it could be easier to remember!!

"Dot" is equally simple: the result is just a simple value ... kind of like a number, "speed", or size.

(Note that of course in ordinary kindergarten arithmetic, the dot just means simple multiplication.  For example 3.4 = 12.  Or "6.a" is "6a".  The result of a dot is nothin more than a number, like 13.3 or 28. It's exactly, totally, the same when dealing with vectors - of course the result of a dot, is, simply a number!)

Regarding making a cross, here's an excellent and entertaining article by some drunk about the two ways you can go when you make that cross (either "up" or "down," so to speak), which is just decided by convention depending on what chipset you're using.

http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/267076/view.html

[image]

Of course, the "cross" if two vectors is just the thing that sticks up when the vectors "cross" -- what else could it be called?  You'll never forget it again!

Comment: A remark only: This convention is related to the Cartesian coordinate system which is related to the right hand with relation to the thumb and the next two fingers. (Excellent answer and of course you now all about my remark, but for the beauty of the answer :-)